# signalr how i can i post a message from server to caller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I am using Signalr 1.1.4 because im still using .net4 so cant upgrade to signalr 2.

Basically i want to post a message from the server to just the caller to avoid messages being sent to any client that did not start the process off.

My hub class looks like this

```
public class UpdateHub : Hub
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Sends the message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="progressMessage">The progress message.</param>
    public void SendMessage(string progressMessage)
    {
        Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).sendMessage(string.Format(progressMessage));
    }
}
```

my javascript looks like this

```
    // get handle to subscriptionUpload hub generated by SignalR 
    var updateHub = $.connection.UpdateHub;

    // establish the connection to the server and start server-side operation
    $.connection.hub.start();

    updateHub.client.sendMessage = function (message)
    {
        $("container").empty();
        $("container").append(message);
    }
```

Now in my controller action method i would like to do something like this

```
UpdateHub hub = new UpdateHub();
hub.SendMessage("process has started");

//continue on with long process

hub.SendMessage("process has ended");
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What we can find in documentation [documentation](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#transience):

> You don't instantiate the Hub class or call its methods from your own
>   code on the server; all that is done for you by the SignalR Hubs
>   pipeline. SignalR creates a new instance of your Hub class each time
>   it needs to handle a Hub operation such as when a client connects,
>   disconnects, or makes a method call to the server.
>
> Because instances of the Hub class are transient, you can't use them
>   to maintain state from one method call to the next. Each time the
>   server receives a method call from a client, a new instance of your
>   Hub class processes the message. To maintain state through multiple
>   connections and method calls, use some other method such as a
>   database, or a static variable on the Hub class, or a different class
>   that does not derive from Hub. If you persist data in memory, using a
>   method such as a static variable on the Hub class, the data will be
>   lost when the app domain recycles.

And then:

> If you want to send messages to clients from your own code that runs
>   outside the Hub class, **you can't do it by instantiating a Hub class
>   instance, but you can do it by getting a reference to the SignalR
>   context object for your Hub class**.

You can get the context of your hub: `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<YourHub>()`

and then you can use it to call methods on the client side like this:

```
context.Clients.All.YourMethod(params);
```

or

```
context.Clients.Client(someConnectionID).YourMethod(params);
```

But in this case you won't be able to use `Context.ConnectionId` in this methods, because you don't have a direct connection to your hub. In this case you will need to store your connections somewhere (static variables, cache, db etc) and then use it to determine which client should be called.

Hope it will help.

Comment: I found out that a connection Id for the client is generated when my process runs. I think I can pass it to my controller using ajax in order to use clients.client (connectionId)

Comment: Yes, like an option.